# Is it time to upgrare to eclipse to ver 3.6.xxx

Tags: android, eclipse

About 2 months ago I was setting up an Android development environment, and noticed a warning on the Android SDK page that stated "There are known issues with the ADT plugin running with Eclipse 3.6. Please stay on 3.5 until further notice." - so 
I posted a question here about this and from the responses decided, to install Eclipse ver 3.5

I never saw a notice that  it was safe to upgrade, but...
- The warning is now missing from the Android SDK page
- I thought I read (maybe I'm wrong, because I can't find it now) a comment that some of the Android tutorials were now assuming Eclipse ver 3.6.1

1. Can I assume it is now safe to upgrade to Android 3.6.1 ?
2. The Eclipse IDE for Java Developers download page still seems to be at 3.6.0 ?

Comments Welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to the latest 3.6 and it was OK except that the content assist for the Android classes was ***very*** slow, i.e you would type 'textView.' (where textView is a TextView) and wait for ages for all the available methods to be shown.

This issue is a known bug reported at
[Code Assist still Slow](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/125fbab9f4f717b1/0f9d2a852e661cba?#0f9d2a852e661cba)

Down near the bottom of this thread, someone identified a fix:

***https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=329288 contains patch
that fixes this issue.
Unfortunately patch is applied only in 3.7 branch.
I have patched org.eclipse.jdt.core from Helios 3.6.1 with the patch
attached in this bug and create a patched plugin.
You can replace your /plugins/
org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.6.1.v_A68_R36x.jar plugin with one from
http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/patches/org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.6...
and restart Eclipse. Content Assists will be much better. Just try it.
Don't forget backup your original plugins.
Peco***

I applied this patch and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is fine, i upgraded my desktop environment to 3.6.1 and everything seems to be running fine.

Confirmed: Here is the link to the requirements page. It now says anything greater than 3.4 will work.

> Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede) or greater

[Eclipse Link Requirements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html)

Comment: Thanks, BUT... When I go to the "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" page and examine the contents of the package, it lists 3.6.0 (NOT 3.6.1) for all the eclipse modules.

Comment: @joe - Well where it listed the requirements for eclipse it used to mention the 3.6 problem. And now it doesn't. gL, if you find anything else be sure to post it here, would like to know my self.

Answer (score 0):

I always used Eclipse Helios 3.6.1 for my android programming and I never had any problems, I don't know what the problems were but I didn't find any. Sometimes my R.java doesn't seem to connect with my other classes but I solve that by either restarting my Eclipse of just clean my project, most of the times clean project works perfectly.

The ADT plugin also works fine. It upgrades correctly and I can see all my versions when I create a new project

I did see people having project to even install the google ADT plugin when looking for new software but I didn't come accross that problem. It just installed the first time. with the new update however it seems that my adb.exe doesn't seem to be in my tools folder and Eclipse looks there, so I just copied it from my platform-tools to my tools folder and got it working.

Comment: You shouldn'tjust move the adb.exe, instead alter your path. From the release notes:                                                "If you are upgrading to SDK Tools r8 from an earlier version, note that the the default installed location for the adb tool has changed from <SDK>/tools/adb to <SDK>/platform-tools/adb. This means that you should add the new location to your PATH and modify any custom build scripts to reference the new location. Copying the adb executable from the new location to the old is not recommended, since subsequent updates to the SDK Tools will delete the file."

Comment: Didn't know that actually, thanks for the info, I'll look into it. but I never had problems with updates but I'll try to get it done the correct way

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to update the 2.3 sdk to 2.3.1 in Eclipse 3.6.1, I had to clean all my projects as well as start Eclipse several times before everything could be installed successfully. Other than that, I've had no problems at all.